# create column from other columns in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

i want to create ids for every row in a new column . which has first four characters of name and last four number of phone number .

example :

```
Name(column) : john Doe(row)
Phone number(column) : 1234567890(row)
```

id should be created as john_7890
this should be done for every row .

Comment: stackoverflow is not for solving tasks of others. if you an error in a code sample post it here.

Comment: Have you tried anything, done any research? As it stands, this is broad, vague, unclear and low effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df["id"] = df["Name"].apply(lambda s: s[:4]) + df["Number"].apply(lambda n: str(n)[-4:])
```

Comment: Why not use the string slicing methods provided by Pandas?

Comment: @AMC Sure you can use it. I forgot that there's a slice method.